# Nested Components created on the fly in Angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, nested, components

I have this plunker example https://embed.plnkr.co/RtZvxv2rPFpLPZGndS0g/ where I have two components created on the fly: ContentComponent and HeaderComponent. I want to reference the HeaderComponent selector in the ContentComponent template like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.template = "<div>This is the {{ name }}</div><app-header></app-header>";
  this.compileTemplate();
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working and the compiler complains: app-header is not a known element.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Is there another way to obtain the same end result?

Comment: You can't add Angular "stuff" like that at runtime - only plain HTML. For what you want you would need to compile a component at runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/2zMCh6elJxh2RInqB6ZZ?p=preview

Comment: did @yurzui's solution help?

Comment: It is finally working! Thank you very much @yurzui!

Comment: Thank you @AngularInDepth.com for teaching me how to use dynamic components. It is amazing what you can do with Angular today. https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: @M.Rauca, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular can't find `app-header` element because HeaderComponent was **neither declared nor imported**

To solve it you can create `SharedModule` that declares and exports `HeaderComponent`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ HeaderComponent],
    exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and finally simply import it in your dynamic module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [decoratedCmp], 
  imports: [SharedModule] <============ this line
})
class RuntimeContentModule { }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2zMCh6elJxh2RInqB6ZZ?p=preview)**